# Create a dataframe on incremental basis

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm writing a code whose end result is a dataframe. This dataframe will be created on incremental basis. I read that the recommended approach to accomplish this is to create a list of list and at the end convert it into a dataframe. Below are major steps

```
dfColumns = ["ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD"]
lst = []

for i in range(5):
    ColA = something
    ColB = something
    ColC = something
    ColD = something

    lst.append([ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD])

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=dfColumns)
```

I am looking for a way such that I dont have to write ColA, ColB.... at 3 places. Is there a way to do something like this `lst.append(dfColumns)`

Comment: I cannot think of a simpler way to do what you want to do. Also technically you're just writing those variables in two places (you cannot really get around writing their name in the columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `DataFrame` from a list of dictionaries:

```py
import pandas

column_names = ["ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD"]
rows = []

for _ in range(5):

    # Explicitly create the row content
    row = {
        "ColA": "something",
        "ColB": "something",
        "ColC": "something",
        "ColD": "something",
    }

    # OR

    # Dynamically create each column from the column names
    row = {key: "something" for key in column_names}

    # Add the row to the list
    rows.append(row)


# Create a dataframe from a list of dicts will automatically find the column names
df = pandas.DataFrame(rows)
```